# Understand Kafka write speed

Tags: java, performance, apache-kafka, kafka-cluster

Given that
1. Five machine Kafka cluster
2. 1 topic with 1 partition
3. persisted storage for msgs
4. Each msg of 1 KB
5. 10 producers

Now, Will the max write capability of this cluster BE EQUAL TO max write capability of one java thread onto a disk?
If No, what will it be?

Comment: Kafka writes to memory before flushing to disk. Not sure why you wouldn't want 5 partitions if you're concerned about speed

Comment: This is a academic question to understand and create mind model..the case I am analying required  persistence

Comment: This is a bad question. Showing close-to-zero previous research efforts. A few strokes and a few minutes of reading will avoid asking artificially "constructed" question, even from academic residents ... >>> https://www.quora.com/Kafka-writes-every-message-to-broker-disk-Still-performance-wise-it-is-better-than-some-of-the-in-memory-message-storing-message-queues-Why-is-that + a few google refinements will get one more inputs on **Why ?** - if indeed interested in and striving to **create a mind model**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only have one partiton then kafka cannot scale your topic and use only one machine out of your 5 instance cluster.

cannot tell how well you code your java but results will be similar to kafka I assume with small differences as kafka is optimised for disk writes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really say it will be "EQUAL TO" because it is not accurate, but yes, the write capacity will be pretty much the same assuming the disk I/O will be your bottle-neck. Take into account that Kafka is optimized for this task and probably will better perform than the naive disk writes of a standard Java application.